# What is the right place to call a function before render in React?

Tags: reactjs, components, react-hooks, render, lifecycle

I have some issue on understandsing the lifecycle in React, so iam using useEffects() since i do understand that it was the right way to call a method before the component rendered (the replacement for componentDidMount ).

```
  useEffect(() => {
    tagSplit = tagArr.split(',');
  });
```

And then i call tagSplit.map() function on the component, but it says that tagSplit.map is not a function

```
{tagSplit.map((item, index) => (
   <div className="styles" key={index}>
      {item}
   </div>
))}
```

Is there something wrong that i need to fix or was it normal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this .

```
function App() {

    const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        let tagSplit = tagArr.split(',');
        setArr(tagSplit);
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            {arr.map((item, index) => (
                <div className="styles" key={index}>
                    {item}
                </div>
            ))}
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: I've tried this and success, but it call 100 times in render and make my page so lag, how does it possible ?

Comment: @Faishal if this does ans to your que than please consider this ans as marked !!

Answer (score 2):

`useEffect` runs AFTER a render and then subsequently as the dependencies change.

So yes, if you have `tagSplit` as something that doesn't support a `map` function initially, it'll give you an error from the first render.

If you want to control the number of times it runs, you should provide a dependency array.

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks),

> Does useEffect run after every render? Yes! By default, it runs both after the first render and after every update. (We will later talk about how to customize this.) Instead of thinking in terms of “mounting” and “updating”, you might find it easier to think that effects happen “after render”. React guarantees the DOM has been updated by the time it runs the effects.

[This article](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) from Dan Abramov's blog should also help understand `useEffect` better

```
const React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default () => {
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState('')

  // this will get reassigned on every render
  let tagSplit = ''

  useEffect(() => {
    // no dependencies array,
    // Runs AFTER EVERY render
    tagSplit = tagArr.split(',');
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    // empty dependencies array
    // RUNS ONLY ONCE AFTER first render
  }, [])


  useEffect(() => {
    // with non-empty dependency array
    // RUNS on first render 
    // AND AFTER every render when `someState` changes
  }, [someState])

  return (
    // Suggestion: add conditions or optional chaining
    {tagSplit && tagSplit.map
        ? tagSplit.map((item, index) => (
            <div className='styles' key={index}>
              {item}
            </div>
          ))
        : null}
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Answering the question's title:

`useEffect` runs **after** the first render, and is not a good tool for the job:

```js
const {useEffect, Fragment} = React

const getItemsFromString = items => items.split(',');
  
const Tags = ({items}) => {
  let itemsArr = [];

  // useEffect will NOT cause a re-render
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect')
    itemsArr = getItemsFromString(items)
  }, [items])

  console.log(itemsArr)

  return itemsArr.map((item, index) => 
    <mark style={{margin: '3px'}} key={index}>{item}</mark>
  )
}

// Render 
ReactDOM.render(<Tags items='foo, bar, baz'/>, root)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

`useMemo` runs **before** the first render.

If you want to run some code once, you can put it inside `useMemo`:

```js
const {useMemo, Fragment} = React

const getItemsFromString = items => items.split(',');
  
const Tags = ({items}) => {
  const itemsArr = useMemo(() => getItemsFromString(items), [items])

  console.log(itemsArr)

  return itemsArr.map((item, index) => <mark style={{margin: '3px'}} key={index}>{item}</mark>)
}

// Render 
ReactDOM.render(<Tags items='foo, bar, baz'/>, root)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

For your specific component, it's obvious there is no dilema at all, as you can directly split the string within the returned JSX:

```
return tagArr.split(',').map((item, index) => 
   <div className="styles" key={index}>
      {item}
   </div>
)
```

But for more complex, performance-heavy transformations, it is best to run them only when needed, and use a cached result by utilizing `useMemo`